# Getting one specific value from get_children array

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, get-children

I have one problem that I'm trying to deal with. I have below array of get_children for Woocommerce order and its suborders created by Dokan plugin, and I'm trying to integrate it with another plugin.
 What I need is to get suborder (child post ID) that belongs to specific seller (post_author). So what I have is:

- Parent post ID -  $reservation->transaction_id -  Order ID
- post_author - $seller_id - returns seller ID

  ```
  $sub_orders = get_children( array(    
  'post_parent' => $reservation->transaction_id,    
  'post_type'   => 'shop_order',    
  'post_status' => array( 
  'wc-pending', 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' 
  )
  ) );
  ```

The array returns:

```
array ( 
1810 => WP_Post::__set_state(array( 
'ID' => 1810, 
'post_author' =>'post_author' =>, 
'post_date' => '2016-10-16 22:13:35', 
'post_date_gmt' => '2016-10-16 22:13:35', 
'post_content' => '', 
'post_title' => 'Order – October 16, 2016 @ 10:13 PM', 
'post_excerpt' => '', 
'post_status' => 'wc-processing', 
'comment_status' => 'open', 
'ping_status' => 'closed', 
'post_password' => 'order_5803fb8de7789', 
'post_name' => 'order-oct-16-2016-1013-pm-3', 
'to_ping' => '', 
'pinged' => '', 
'post_modified' => '2016-10-16 22:13:35', 
'post_modified_gmt' => '2016-10-16 22:13:35', 
'post_content_filtered' => '', 
'post_parent' => 1808, 
'guid' => 'https://example.com/?post_type=shop_order&p=1810', 
'menu_order' => 0, 'post_type' => 'shop_order', 
'post_mime_type' => '', 
'comment_count' => '1', 
'filter' => 'raw', )), 
1809 => WP_Post::__set_state(array(
 'ID' => 1809, 
 'post_author' => '2', 
 'post_date' => '2016-10-16 22:13:34', 
 'post_date_gmt' => '2016-10-16 22:13:34', 
 'post_content' => '', 
 'post_title' => 'Order – October 16, 2016 @ 10:13 PM', 
 'post_excerpt' => '', 
 'post_status' => 'wc-completed', 
 'comment_status' => 'open', 
 'ping_status' => 'closed', 
 'post_password' => 'order_5803fb8dd09ed', 
 'post_name' => 'order-oct-16-2016-1013-pm-2', 
 'to_ping' => '', 'pinged' => '', 
 'post_modified' => '2016-10-16 23:48:58', 
 'post_modified_gmt' => '2016-10-16 23:48:58', 
 'post_content_filtered' => '', 
 'post_parent' => 1808, 
 'guid' => 'https://example.com/?post_type=shop_order&p=1809', 
 'menu_order' => 0, 
 'post_type' => 'shop_order', 
 'post_mime_type' => '', 
 'comment_count' => '2', 
 'filter' => 'raw', )), )
```

Comment: The title of the question is confusing after reading the question's text Can you please clarify it more? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query by a *post author* , you can try the `author` input argument:

```
$sub_orders = get_children( 
    array(    
        'author'      => $seller_id,
        'post_parent' => $reservation->transaction_id,    
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',    
        'post_status' => array( 
            'wc-pending', 
            'wc-completed', 
            'wc-processing', 
            'wc-on-hold' 
        )
    ) 
);
```

Note that `get_children()` calls `get_posts()`, that is again a wrapper for `WP_Query`, so you can use the  `author_name`, `author__in` and `author__not_in` input arguments as well.